# PATH as variable in OPENJSON

Tags: sql-server, json, function, t-sql

I want to make a function, which adds value to json-array only if it's not present there. I write a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (@json nvarchar(max), @arr nvarchar(max), @value nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json,@arr) WHERE [value] =  @value)
    SET @json=JSON_MODIFY(@json,'append '+@arr,@value)
    RETURN @json
END
```

But I got error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure JSON_ARRAY_APPEND, Line 5 [Batch
>   Start Line 6] Incorrect syntax near '@arr'.

I see it is because I pass path into OPENJSON as variable @arr

How to do this in a right way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made this way

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.JSON_ARRAY_APPEND (@json nvarchar(max), @arr nvarchar(max), @value nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json) WHERE [value] =  @value AND  [key] = RIGHT(@arr,LEN(@arr)-2))
        SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json,'append '+@arr,@value)
    RETURN @json
END
GO
```